# Printing out python output to an html file

Tags: html, python-3.x

I am writing a script to print the output to an html file. I am stuck on the format of my output. Below is my code:

```
def printTohtml(Alist):
    myfile = open('zip_files.html', 'w')
    html =  """<html>
    <head></head>
    <body><p></p>{htmlText}</body>
    </html>"""

    title = "Study - User - zip file -  Last date modified"
    myfile.write(html.format(htmlText = title))
    for newL in Alist:
        for j in newL:
            if j == newL[-1]:
                myfile.write(html.format(htmlText=j))
            else:
                message = j + ', '
                myfile.write(html.format(htmlText = message))
    myfile.close()

Alist =  [['123', 'user1', 'New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip', '05-24-17'],
['123', 'user2', 'Iam.zip', '05-19-17'], ['abcd', 'Letsee.zip', '05-22-17'],
['Here', 'whichTwo.zip', '06-01-17']]

printTohtml(Alist)
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
Study - User - zip file -  Last date modified
123, user1, New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip, 05-24-17
123, user2, Iam.zip, 05-19-17
abcd, Letsee.zip, 05-22-17
Here, whichTwo.zip, 06-01-17
```

But my code is giving me everything on its own line. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance for your help!

My Output:

```
Study - User - zip file - Last date modified 

123, 

user1, 

New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip, 

05-24-17 

123, 

user2, 

Iam.zip, 

05-19-17 

abcd, 

Letsee.zip, 

05-22-17 

Here, 

whichTwo.zip, 

06-01-17
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like that. I haven't tested but this will create the string first and then write it to the file. Might be faster for avoiding multiple writes but I am not sure how python is handling that on the background.

```
def printTohtml(Alist):
    myfile = open('zip_files.html', 'w')
    html =  """<html>
    <head></head>
    <body><p></p>{htmlText}</body>
    </html>"""

    title = "Study - User - zip file -  Last date modified"
    Alist = [title] + [", ".join(line) for line in Alist]
    myfile.write(html.format(htmlText = "\n".join(Alist)))

    myfile.close()

Alist =  [['123', 'user1', 'New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip', '05-24-17'],
['123', 'user2', 'Iam.zip', '05-19-17'], ['abcd', 'Letsee.zip', '05-22-17'],
['Here', 'whichTwo.zip', '06-01-17']]

printTohtml(Alist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're including the html, body and paragraph tags every time you write a line to your file.

Why don't you concatenate your string, separating the lines with `<br>` tags, and then load them into your file, like so:

```
def printTohtml(Alist):
    myfile = open('zip_files.html', 'w')
    html =  """<html>
    <head></head>
    <body><p>{htmlText}</p></body>
    </html>"""

    complete_string = "Study - User - zip file -  Last date modified"
    for newL in Alist:
        for j in newL:
            if j == newL[-1]:
                complete_string += j + "<br>"
            else:
                message = j + ', '
                complete_string += message + "<br>"
    myfile.write(html.format(htmlText = complete_string))
    myfile.close()
```

Also, your template placeholder is in the wrong spot, it should be between your paragraph tags.